# Integer overflow with subtraction

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, integer-overflow

Okay so I need to implement a method that returns zero or one depending on if x-y results in an overflow.

```
Example: subTract(0x80000000,0x80000000) = 1,
         subTract(0x80000000,0x70000000) = 0,
```

I'm NOT looking for an implementation of this method. I don't understand which one supposedly results in an overflow, and that making it nearly impossible to start. Why does one of these cause an overflow? What defines an overflow with subtraction.

assume the system uses 2's complement and a 32-bit representation of ints

Comment: Shouldn't the 0 and 1 results be the other way around? `0x80000000` minus a positive number will overflow (since it was the lower representable number), but `0x80000000 - 0x80000000` (and any other `x - x`) just results in zero (without overflow).

Comment: @harold I take "returns zero or one depending on if x-y results in an overflow" to 1) the return value is 0 or 1 and 2) it depends somehow on subtraction overflow.  Unfortunately it is ambiguous as to if 0 or 1 implies overflow.  I agree with you that `1` should imply overflow and it looks backwards in this case.

Comment: I have no idea what a 1 or 0 means, that was largely the point of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing the subtraction with 32-bit and 64-bit.

1:No overflow.  The difference of `x-x` is `0` and is representable as a 32-bit `int`.  This is expected regardless of what integer value/type `x` may be.

0:Overflow.  The difference of `x-y` (or `-2147483648 - 1879048192`) is arithmetically `-4026531840` and is *not* representable as a 32-bit `int`.  The result of the below code provided a difference of `268435456`.  But `int` overflow is undefined behavior, so the result here may differ on another machine.

Overflow with subtraction occurs when the arithmetically correct difference does not match the computed difference.

```
void subtest(void) {
  int32_t x = 0x80000000;
  int32_t y = 0x70000000;

  printf("x = %" PRId32 "\n", x);
  printf("y = %" PRId32 "\n", y);

  printf("x-x = %" PRId32 "\n", x-x);
  printf("x-y = %" PRId32 "\n\n", x-y);

  int64_t x2 = x;
  int64_t y2 = y;

  printf("x2 = %" PRId64 "\n", x2);
  printf("y2 = %" PRId64 "\n", y2);

  printf("x2-x2 = %" PRId64 "\n", x2-x2);
  printf("x2-y2 = %" PRId64 "\n", x2-y2);
}

x = -2147483648
y = 1879048192
x-x = 0
x-y = 268435456

x2 = -2147483648
y2 = 1879048192
x2-x2 = 0
x2-y2 = -4026531840
```